# ZSH regex pattern matches in tester but not in use

Tags: regex, bash, zsh

In a zsh shell script (sdk.sh) I have a command that can be input four ways, according to user preference. The script should figure out which pattern the input is, then act on it accordingly.

My regexes work in https://www.regextester.com/107384 but not in the script and I can't figure out why.

Input value on execution: `./sdk.sh sitename.stage PSD-00000`

### Regexes

Multiple patterns are required so that regardless of the input, the output (which will be a shell command) will be structured as `sitename.stage PSD-12345`

```bash
pattern1="^([A-z0-9])+\.stage+\s+(PSD-)+[0-9]+$"    ## ex: sitename.stage PSD-00000
pattern2="^([A-z0-9])+\s+(PSD-)+[0-9]+$"            ## ex: sitename PSD-00000
pattern3="^([A-z0-9])+\s+[0-9]+$"                   ## ex: sitename 00000
pattern4="^([A-z0-9])+\.stage+\s+[0-9]+$"           ## ex: sitename.stage 00000
```

### Conditional Tests

These regexes find a match at https://www.regextester.com/107384 both with and without the start `^` and end `$` characters, but they do not find matches here.

```bash
# Check that input value exists and which pattern it matches

if [[ -n "$value" ]]; then
  echo "0. Inputted value: ${value}"

  if [[ "$value" =~ $pattern1 ]];  ## ex: sitename.stage PSD-00000
  then
    sitePhase=$value
    echo "1. value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"

  elif [[ "$value" =~ $pattern2 ]];  ## ex: sitename PSD-00000
  then
    sitePhase="$value (add .stage to first input)"
    echo "2. value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"

  elif [[ "$value" =~ $pattern3 ]]; ## ex: sitename 00000
  then
    sitePhase="$value (add .stage to first input, PSD- to second input"
    echo "3.  value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"

  elif [[ "$value" =~ $fullPattern4 ]]; ## ex: sitename.stage 00000
  then
    echo "4.  value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"

  else
    echo "No matches"
  fi
fi
```

### Output

```
0. Inputted value: equinix.stage PSD-00000
No matches
```

Indicates that `$value` has value, and should therefore be able to be tested, and that for whatever reason, the regexes that match on the tester, don't match in the script.

### Questions

1. What am I missing?
2. Is it important to have the start `^` and end `$` characters in this
   case? Why/not?
3. Is zsh regex different from bash regex? If so I can't really find
   any easily discoverable documentation about this online.

Comment: Do you intentionally use several regex patterns? What about a single `^[[:alnum:]]+(\.stage)?([[:space:]](PSD-)?)?[0-9]+$`?

Comment: Yes, I do, because each one needs to be dealt with separately to get the correct final output depending on the input. I'll make a note of that. Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, using this single regex, you can analyze what group captured and act accordingly.

Comment: I think `\s` is not recognized in your patterns. Try with `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`.

Comment: The regex works, thanks, but how am I to call it in an if statement, for example, `if [ ".space" = $match[1] ]` is a syntax error because of the array braces. Wasn't able to find documentation on this.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that I should do something like `someVar=$match[0]` but executing that claims that 'match: unbound varible' ... ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244840/discussion-between-maxrocket-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please see https://ideone.com/Cl9mMX. However, this is for Bash, not zsh.

Comment: See [code demo](https://tio.run/##pZNda4MwGIXv/RWHVKrSVfqxmzmkN7vZzSjs0lkIGqdgY2nSMbqPv@5MIq2dtLDOq3jyvjnPeaN7kdf1Gy13LHREIRmna@YLSV8Zls8P44l6HGtDpWRbHjqrKApoyXfrII5H7oup9BZuI4sNTVgju6rPW3iLaDK@i0e2YxUZoghjDmJrJ4I4vofMGbcAluQVyMTHI9/sGpcUuiaA/aEXX8SCOeDQHX7DbokOJwGDAdh7gHMhGit0QNZUJnk0jQmGQ3SlWV@axyfE0B7LnAoWGiQtmiBT3/AjhNnD57FciYcXorpY2WNqAc7493KeJuygteOCS9MU7TRkhazYColCDdsjHfDZleD7Hvgl5STK7yTXpbjRE1CiYEnFU6N2o819/PdSphe4W6ojvXG9/aNrVqi/oRTdr@mpgvZnQpU0FVlR1z8) for zsh

Comment: Thank you, however I'm still getting `line 127: match[1]: unbound variable` on execution for `if [[ -n "${match[1]}" ]]` or     `if [[ -n "$match[1]" ]]` and I have no idea why

Comment: Shared the IDE screenshot with syntax error highlighting for the code you shared. No idea why it works in the zsh playground but not on my system

Comment: Hm, and if you use `setopt match`? :)

Comment: Doesn't work. Now it's not even recognizing `setopt BASH_REMATCH` so I don't know WHAT's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to match letters only, `[A-z]` is not the right pattern, it should be `[A-Za-z]`, but here, since you need to match alphanumerics, `[[:alnum:]]` seems a better counterpart.

In your regex, `\s` is not parsed as whitespace pattern, but as a mere `s` letter pattern.

I suggest using a single regex with capturing groups that will match all kinds of input strings. Then, you can check if specific groups participated in the match or not, and implement the appropriate logic.

Here is an example:

```sh
setopt BASH_REMATCH
value='sitename.stage PSD-00000'
pattern='^[[:alnum:]]+(\.stage)?([[:space:]](PSD-)?)?[0-9]+$'
if [[ -n "$value" ]]; then
  echo "0. Inputted value: ${value}"
 if [[ "$value" =~ $pattern ]]; then  ## ex: sitename.stage PSD-00000
   if [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" &&  -n "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" &&  -n "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" ]]; then
    sitePhase=$value
    echo "1. value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"
   elif [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" && -n "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" ]]; then  ## ex: sitename PSD-00000
    sitePhase="$value (add .stage to first input)"
    echo "2. value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"
   elif [[ -z "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" && -z "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" && -z "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" ]]; then ## ex: sitename 00000
    sitePhase="$value (add .stage to first input, PSD- to second input"
    echo "3.  value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"
   elif [[ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ]]; then ## ex: sitename.stage 00000
    echo "4.  value = $value | sitePhase = $sitePhase"
   fi
  else
    echo "No matches"
  fi
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://tio.run/##rZNLT4NAFIX3/IoTSgqklvThRgxp6iOpC01j3SGaCQxCQoF0psa01r@ODGBL1da0kdVw7p0557sDCxZkGaM8STkuhpPR8/317fDhciS9kmhOLZWFnMZkSg3GyQvFeHLV7ohHlVLCOZ3Flvpk2yaJ4vnUdJyW9lh26gMtl1lKXJrLmtinD/SB3WmfOS1FlUIfto12DFkpnGQ4zjl4QGMJoG6QQO4YuInTee7ioegxoSyLxUqWUB6w3m19QKkSrU8CGg3QNxO7IHIr1IIs6wOwu85KRrOJ32q9PbW@qNVgUNiPA8KoVaYtxJKxa5RosFDW8L5pF@L6RRa7aLQz7lekvxL9GMr2OGphq9lCI56HanQ8gR/OGEcobkaXayi9I1EWu1EOKm1Tfoc8DvCkGI4QGXWT2CvVOnXfwH/dYHcfQBVvg1Hanx5o74fi94pY/Ru8SzAl3A0oEy15hx9m2Sc) printing the expected

```
0. Inputted value: sitename.stage PSD-00000
1. value = sitename.stage PSD-00000 | sitePhase = sitename.stage PSD-00000
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(\.stage)?` - Group 1 (optional): `.stage` string
- `([[:space:]](PSD-)?)?` - Group 2 (optional): a whitespace and then an optional Group 3 capturing a `PSD-` string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.